# Binary tree with add a node at a specific existing node

Tags: java, algorithm, tree, binary-tree

I'm trying to create a binary tree in Java to model the way in a perfect maze.

Each node `Node<T>` can have 2 children (`Node<T> left` and `Node<T> right`).
Each node is definited with `T data` as (x,y) coordinates.

For add a new node, I need to find the actual node (current position) :

`previousPosition = actualPosition;
move();
tree.addNode(previousPosition, actualPosition);`

And addNode must me search the node `previousPosition` for add a child (`actualPosition`) to left or rigth (depending of null child).

I need your help.

My code:

```
public class BinaryTree<T> {
    // Root node pointer. Will be null for an empty tree.
    private Node root;
    /*
--Node--
The binary tree is built using this nested node class.
Each node stores one data element, and has left and right
sub-tree pointer which may be null.
The node is a "dumb" nested class -- we just use it for
storage; it does not have any methods.
     */
    private static class Node<T> {
        Node<T> left;
        Node<T> right;
        T data;
        Node(T newData) {
            left = null;
            right = null;
            data = newData;
        }
    }
...
...
...
private Node<T> insert(Node<T> node, T parent, T data) {
        if(node.data.equals(parent)) {          
            if(node.left == null) {             
                node.left = new Node<T>(data);              
            } else if (node.right == null) {                
                node.right = new Node<T>(data);             
            } else {
                System.out.println("Children are not nulls");
            }

        } else {
            if(node.left != null) {
                insert(node.left, parent, data);                
            }
            if(node.right != null) {
                insert(node.right, parent, data);               
            }
        }       
        return node;
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok let me try to guide you a little bit because this question is a bit confusing. Essentially you need to create a variable called currentPosition and every time you call the move() method just set the node you move to as the value of currentPosition. This may be more simplistic than you need so please let me know if that is not what you needed!